# A Photoshop term for "body double" or "doppelgänger"

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, terminology

I saw a tutorial on TV. The tutorial was like this:

> Take your snap sitting on chair, another standing on left side of chair and then last one standing on the right side of the chair. Now, use Photoshop to merge these three pics. After everything it will be three look alike on the pic.

Now, I want to search this tutorial on web but I don't know what to write for "How to create *_*_ in Photoshop"? Please suggest.

**Edit** I tried *body double* and *doppelgänger* but it is not the word I am looking for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Clone**

[Clone Yourself Using Adobe Photoshop](http://www.instructables.com/id/Clone-Yourself-Using-Adobe-Photoshop/)

Comment: yes clone is the word :). But the correct tut for cloning yourself is: http://www.mrmalique.com/index.php/tutorial-how-to-create-your-own-clones/

Comment: Annoying ad on that site